# Couldn't attend IEEE Conference and unable to present my paper

Tags: publications, conference, paper-submission, ieee

My paper was accepted at an IEEE conference. I paid my registration fees even registered for doing a physical presentation( there was an option for video presentation). But when I will enter the country, immigration office restricted my entry due to some visa issues. I had to go back. Thus, I couldn't attend the conference.

Now, will my paper in the end counted as an accepted paper and will add in IEEE Xplore?

Comment: Contact the conference organizers - it's their decision...

Comment: I hope you contacted them immediately.

Comment: You need to provide all the details and proof of what you have faced with immigration or VISA related issue with the organizer. Most likely, you might have to arrange alternative speaker or video presentation for your paper and send to the session chair.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is likely that the answer in your case is "no", as IEEE has a clear [no-show policy](https://www.ieee.org/conferences/organizers/handling-nonpresented-papers.html) the organizers have to follow. Talk to them, but keep your expectations low.

Comment: Actually, that policy is not so strict, and  I'd say that the answer is rather _maybe_.